# Awk: Convert notation of a number while I multiply columns

Tags: awk, scientific-notation

Hi guys I have the following lines:

```
A=3.5e30
B=4.345e40
```

(File contains columns with numbers in this notation 1.2345678D+10)

```
sed 's/D/E/g' File | awk '{print $1, $6*'$A', 10^($9)*'$B', $13, $8}' > File2
```

The output that I'm getting is:

```
3.168808781403E+02 29825999184755995994350665720659968 71343531834366140263241767594070376448 ... etc
```

How can I have the 2nd and 3rd column with the same notation as in the first column? I.e,

Instead of having : `71343531834366140263241767594070376448`

I want: `7.134353183436E+37`

Just to let you know the answer is:

```
 sed 's/D/E/g' File | awk '{printf "%.12E %.12E %.12E %.12E %.12E\n", $1, $6*'$A', 10^($9)*'$B', $13,$8 }' > File2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the so called scientific notation use printf and `%E` format specifier.

Example:

```
echo 71343531834366140263241767594070376448 | awk '{printf "%E",$1}'
```

Output:

```
7.134353E+37
```

Comment: Nice but how I do this in the same line? (and I have different columns)

Comment: Just use printf instead of print: `awk '{printf "%E %E %E ...", $1, $6*'$A', 10^($9)*'$B', $13, $8 ... `

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf("%E\n", 71343531834366140263241767594070376448); }'
7.134353E+37
```

Comment: Nice but how I do this in the same line? (and I have different columns)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `printf()` instead of `print()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { printf "%e\n", 282048204209482034890 }' /dev/null
2.820482e+20
```

Comment: Thanks but then I have to do this in another line, right?

Comment: Yup; it's just an example to show the result on the command line. No need for a BEGIN block in your code.

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of problems you need to fix in your codes:

- usage of shell var in awk:

  ```
  awk -v awkVar1="$A" -v awkVar2="$B" ... '{use awkVar1 without $}' file
  ```
- to get scientific-notation format, you need define the format with `printf`, one of `%E, %e, %g, %G` would be useful for you.